# which point is definitly on this parabola?

Tags: analytic-geometry, conic-sections

Vertex of a parabola is on y axis. and the point (4,7) is on this parabola.

which one of these points definitly on the parabola : (-4,7),(2,7),(0,11),(-2,7) or (0,-5)

Let $(0,b)$ be the vertex point. so the equation should be $y=ax^2+b$ or $x=c(y-b)^2$ 
so There are 4 possible parabolas

$16a+b=7$

$4=c(7-b)^2$

$c=\frac{1}{64a^2}$

shouldnt it give us more information?

Answer (score 0):

Although the parabola is not completely described, you do have enough information to check whether one of the listed points is on the parabola. Specifically, $(-4,7)$ **must** be on the parabola because its center is on the y-axis.

Regarding the other points: $(2,7)$ cannot be on the parabola because it conflicts with $(4,7)$ (and by extension neither can $(-2,7)$). Either $(0,11)$ or $(0,-5)$ **might** be the vertices but you can't say for sure.

Comment: in this equation $x=c(y-b)^2$ c>0 . so x>0

Comment: but what if c is negative?

Comment: Indeed, what would it mean if x>0? It's a parabola, so its domain is all x in R, right? You actually don't need any equations to answer this question -- just think about the shape of the graph and its symmetry.

Comment: I forgot to add "may be ". if the parabola is form of $x=c(y-b)^2$. (-4,7) cant be on it because  $c=\frac{1}{64a^2}>0$

Comment: By your equation, the parabola is not defined at x=0, either -- so it couldn't have a vertex on the y-axis, which contradicts the specifications of the problem! Again, **you don't need equations to solve this**.